# Excel 2016 and Toad for oracle outputs different

Tags: sql, oracle, excel, toad, vba

I have an Excel file that executes an oracle (12c) procedure via VBA, passing in some input parameters, and then retrieves about 20 rows of data from the procedure into the worksheet.

When I execute the procedure in Toad for Oracle, a particular row shows a correct numeric value (In a particular example - 50, or 49.3 depending on an input date range), however when executed from Excel - the value is missing completely...

The particular query essentially averages up a bunch of whole numbers over a date range. Fairly basic... but Excel shows nothing in the cell.

Has anyone ever experienced this ?

Thanks

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim Oracon As ADODB.Connection
Dim recset As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim StartDate1 As New ADODB.Parameter
Dim StartDate2 As New ADODB.Parameter
Dim EndDate1 As New ADODB.Parameter
Dim EndDate2 As New ADODB.Parameter
Dim BooleanParameter1 As New ADODB.Parameter
Dim NumParam1 As New ADODB.Parameter
Dim NumParam2 As New ADODB.Parameter
Dim objErr As ADODB.Error
Dim DataOutput As Worksheet

'Setup connection '
Set Oracon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Oracon.ConnectionString = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;" & _
                      "Data Source=MyDBName;" & _
                      "User ID=Username;" & _
                      "Password=Password;"
Oracon.Open
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = Oracon
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = "MySchema.MyPackageName.MyProcedureName" 'The procedure name


'Append parameters to procedure '
With cmd.Parameters
.Append cmd.CreateParameter(StartDate1, adDate, adParamInput, 21, Range("StartDate1").Value)
.Append cmd.CreateParameter(EndDate1, adDate, adParamInput, 21, Range("EndDate1").Value)
.Append cmd.CreateParameter(StartDate2, adDate, adParamInput, 21, Range("StartDate2").Value)
.Append cmd.CreateParameter(EndDate2, adDate, adParamInput, 21, Range("EndDate2").Value)
.Append cmd.CreateParameter(BooleanParameter1, adChar, adParamInput, 1, Range("F1").Value)
.Append cmd.CreateParameter(NumParam1, adNumeric, adParamInput, 9, Range("F2").Value)
.Append cmd.CreateParameter(NumParam2, adNumeric, adParamInput, 9, Range("F3").Value)
End With

' Enable PLSQLRSet property '
cmd.Properties("PLSQLRSet") = True

Set recset = cmd.Execute

' Disable PLSQLRSet property '
cmd.Properties("PLSQLRSet") = False

Set DataOutput = Worksheets(1)
DataOutput.Activate

Range("A9:L250").Select

Selection.ClearContents

Do While Not recset.EOF
DataOutput.Cells(9, 1).CopyFromRecordset recset
Loop

recset.Close
Set recset = Nothing
Set cmd = Nothing

Exit Sub

err_test:
     MsgBox Error$
For Each objErr In Oracon.Errors
    MsgBox objErr.Description
Next
Oracon.Errors.Clear
Resume Next


End Sub
```

Comment: "an Excel file that executes an oracle (12c) procedure via VBA, passing in some input parameters": Please show the `VBA` calling the oracle procedure, especially how it is passing the input parameters and from where those parameters are taken from.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the code there in a code sample section. As you see, code does not fit into a comment.

Comment: Thanks for that - updated

Comment: What have you tried for debugging? In my opinion none of your `cmd.CreateParameter` will work since [CreateParameter Method (ADO)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/createparameter-method-ado) expects a string as the first parameter as the name of the Parameter object and not a parameter object. So for example `.Append cmd.CreateParameter("StartDate1", adDate, adParamInput, , Range("StartDate1").Value)` if "StartDate1" is the name of the parameter in your procedure.